# informations are not written to a file why?

Tags: vb.net

iam trying to write information about customer from textboxes to a file.txt.
when iam clicking save button, stream is opened, then i used method writeline(txtboxevalues)
but no information are written to the txt file any help in that??
THanks..

Comment: @sam - helps to post your code.

Answer (score 5):

You need to close your file/stream at the end of your manipulations to commit the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Flush() to flush the buffered data to the file.